# Append text to node

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Iam using d3.js to create a forced graph.
Array nodes and links are filled dynamically. After I'am calling function start()

```
function start() {
    link = link.data(force.links(), function (d) {
        return d.source.id + "-" + d.target.id;
    });

    link.enter().insert("line", ".node").attr("class", "link");
    link.exit().remove();
    node = node.data(force.nodes(), function (d) { return d.id; });
    var nodeEnter = node.enter()
        .append("circle")
        .attr("r", 8);
    nodeEnter.append("text")
        .attr("dx", -40)
        .attr("dy", 55)
        .text(function (d) { return d.id });
    node.exit().remove();

    force.start(); 
 }
```

Nodes are OK, links are OK, **but the text is not visible!**
How can I correctly append the text node in this case?

Comment: Why do you use - in dx...??

Comment: Get to know of attributes at [SVG - Text Elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/text.html#TextElement) but before this I guess you should add text to nodes after the force layout stops to interact.

Answer (score 0):

You're appending a text node to a circle node, which is not valid SVG. Instead you should do something like:

```
var nodeEnter = node.enter()
  .append('g')
  .style("transform", "translate(...)")// Here you'll probably want to translate the group)
```

And then nest both circle and text inside the group:

```
nodeEnter
  .append('circle')
  .attr("r", 8);

nodeEnter.append("text")
  .attr("dx", -40)
  .attr("dy", 55)
  .text(function (d) { return d.id });
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer. I tested group element

```
node = node.data(force.nodes(), function (d) { return d.id; });

var NodeEnter = node.enter()
.append("g");

NodeEnter.append("circle")
              .attr("r", 8);
```

Unfortunately, I see only one circle in the corner of the screen. 
Generated svg for 4 nodes is

```
<svg height="500" width="960">
<line>
...
y1="326.81906005822043" x1="454.86800328354803" 
... </line>
<g cy="326.81906005822043" cx="454.86800328354803">
<circle r="8"></circle>
</g>
...
</svg></div>
```

Also "g" element is in OK position on link(node). Cirle is inside element. Yet I see element in corner in screen